# Collapse a SearchView from a Toolbar not set as an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I don't know how to collapse a SearchView without a MenuItem and I don't know how to get a MenuItem from a ToolBar that isn't an ActionBar

It's easy enough to add a SearchView to a Toolbar:

```
Toolbar mToolbar        = (Toolbar) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu);
```

menu/search_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_grey_search"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

I can get ahold of a SearchView and add an OnQueryTextListener() like so:

```
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                ToastUtils.makeText("Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchView);               
                return true;
           }

          @Override public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {return false;}
    });
```

But, without a `MenuItem` I cannot call `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchViewMenuItem)`.

Can someone let me know how to get a MenuItem from a **none-ActionBar** Toolbar.

**EDIT**

I hoped that `mToolbar.collapseActionView();` was the solution, but this has no visible effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold a refrence to SearchView -> mSearchView.
Then where ever u want to collapse it just call

```
mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
```

Comment: Well, I'll be darned, that actually works. Why the heck has it been labeled "on"ActionViewCollapsed()? Aren't methods prefaced with "on" called in reaction to an event happening, not themselves initiators of events?

Comment: Agreed. But that the method u were looking for :)